# Why screenshot of same content appears more saturated on iPad 3 retina vs. Macbook Air LCD?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen-capture, ipad

When I scale a screenshot of the same image from my iPad 3 retina to that on my MB Air the resulting image appears more saturated (unsure if it's a uniform saturation). Why does this happen? Can I transform my screenshot from my LCD monitor to match a screenshot from my iPad 3 by changing the resolution, saturation, contrast, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You could, but how would you know which is correct?

You would need accurate profiles for both screens. This could be done with colorimeter hardware/software, something like [ColorMunki](http://xritephoto.com/custom_page.aspx?PageID=345) *(No affiliation, it's just what I use myself)*, which can calibrate *both* your Mac & [iPad](http://blog.xritephoto.com/2014/03/x-rite-colortrue-color-management-ipads-tablets-smartphones/) screens [also PCs, if you have them]

An app like Photoshop [& possibly Gimp, though I've never used it] could then do the translation between the two, though once your screens are correctly calibrated, you may not need to.